# Error when executing jdbc connection in cmd

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using oracle 12c and want to learn using cmd so that I know what happens when I click build/run on IDE(more like having general idea)

JDBCCheck.java:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
public class JDBCCheck
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException
    {
        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost:1521:oracle");
        Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
        // Create Oracle DatabaseMetaData object
        DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
        // gets driver info:
        System.out.println("JDBC driver version is " + meta.getDriverVersion());
    }
}
```

I have set the classpath

```
>echo %CLASSPATH%
    C:\OracleInstalation\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar;
C:\OracleInstalation\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jlib\orai18n.jar
```

JDBC driver check

```
>java -jar .\ojdbc7.jar
Oracle 12.1.0.1.0 JDBC 4.1 compiled with JDK7 on Thu_Apr_04_15:09:24_PDT_2013
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Thu Dec 24 20:52:27 IST 2015
```

This code compiled successfully but

```
>java JDBCCheck
Error: Could not find or load main class JDBCCheck
```

I checked `JDBCCheck.class` in the directory and it is present

Then I created a project in JCreator with the same code and added the archives to the project, it successfully ran

output:

```
JDBC driver version is 12.1.0.1.0
```

Why am I getting the error when executing in cmd or can it be executed from cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `oracle.jdbc.*` classes, as they are database specific. The `java.sql.*` layer is there to keep your code database agnostic.

As for your problem with running the class, you need to make sure that it's in the classpath. Easiest way is to add the current directory `.` (in addition to other needed jars) in the commandline such as: `java -cp .;some.jar;other/library.jar JDBCCheck`

It would also be advisable to put your class in a package, in which case you would run it as above, except the classname would be `my.package.JDBCCheck` and you would run it in the parent directory that contains the subdirectories (and classfile) `my/package/JDBCCheck.class`.

Comment: I also added `.;` in the CLASSPATH variable and it also works, so in case multiple directory in CLASSPATH,  `.;` should be added?, previously I used CLASSPATH with only one directory in it and I didn't add `.;` still it worked.

Comment: I am studying database connectivity from Oracle doc and the code in the question is an sample program in it. Any good reference to db connection using `java.sql.*`

Comment: Any Java SQL tutorial. It's rarer to see someone using the database specific classes than the Java interfaces.